# Absolutely zero spacing in ListView between items

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView`:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/log_output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
```

With a custom `ArrayAdapter` using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/log_line_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

As you can see, I have done my best to disable the divider in the list view. However, I still see maybe 1-2 pixels of extra pixels between items (vertically). I'd like to eliminate this mysterious extra spacing if possible, as it makes the text appear double-spaced to a degree. How can I get rid of the extra spacing?

### EDIT:

Screenshot of the list view. Notice that the spacing after word wrapping is much thinner (about 1-2 rows of pixels). Each new item in the list begins with `--`. Notice new items added to the list have slightly greater spacing. Ideally I want the spacing used in word wrapping to be the same spacing between list items.

[image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot so we can see the extra space?

Comment: @drawinfinity: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are seeing the extra space being left for accents and other ascenders / descenders in the font? You can try disabling this by setting `android:includeFontPadding="false"` in your TextView.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding

Comment: Yep, that was it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `android:divider="0dp"`